# Nodejs process.stdout.write() to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a quick question. I want to save the value (string) of this statement:

```
process.stdout.write(d);
```

in a variable. But all my attempts failed so how is it done?

```
res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);         
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
var str = "";

res.on('data', (d) => {
   str+=d;
}).on('end',()=>{
   console.log(str);
});
```

Here we append the data `d` we get from stream, we append it to `str` variable & the print the `str` once the stream completes reading